# How to make Accordion Dynamic - Using Angular 6

Tags: angular, accordion

1. How to make Accordion Dynamic 
   like if we click on particular panel then it should display that portion only
2. How we can expand all collapse by clicking on a tag.

[image]

[image]
[image]
    export class HomeComponent implements OnInit {

```
  public homeDataviews = [];
  notes: Array<Note>;

  constructor(private _homeDataService: HomeDataService) {
    this.notes = [];
   }

  ngOnInit() {
    this._homeDataService.getViewData()
      .subscribe(data => this.homeDataviews = data);

  }
```

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Please, add your code as text and not as image.

Comment: Can you please show us the relevant typescript part and what you've exactly tried to accomplish the goal? Also, you should provide the **code** instead of a screenshot of it, otherwise it gets quite hard to properly help you.

Comment: only bootstrap code i had written, only for API data displaying m using TS, Please Check the TS code

Comment: @Rahul, I think this is what you required https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53369784/collapsible-accordion-in-angular and it also has working example and it was made only in angular and typescript..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi there Rahul and welcome to Stack Overflow.

In order to see what is going on with your example of code, we would require to be able to have insight on any of your code related to the problem and the subject you are trying to achieve.
(See: Keep code of question "[minimal](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)")

I do not have much knowledge about Angular so I am not sure if I can help you in that regard. However if you do not require your subject to work around Angular code, I found a perfectly working example of an accordion using just HTML, CSS and JavaScript on W3Schools: [Link](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/tryit.asp?filename=tryhow_js_accordion_symbol).

Please let me know if you have any further questions.

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/n3kuc5s6/)

```js
var acc = document.getElementsByClassName("accordion");
var i;

for (i = 0; i < acc.length; i++) {
  acc[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
    this.classList.toggle("active");
    var panel = this.nextElementSibling;
    if (panel.style.maxHeight){
      panel.style.maxHeight = null;
    } else {
      panel.style.maxHeight = panel.scrollHeight + "px";
    } 
  });
}
```

```css
.accordion {
  background-color: #eee;
  color: #444;
  cursor: pointer;
  padding: 18px;
  width: 100%;
  border: none;
  text-align: left;
  outline: none;
  font-size: 15px;
  transition: 0.4s;
}

.active, .accordion:hover {
  background-color: #ccc;
}

.accordion:after {
  content: '\002B';
  color: #777;
  font-weight: bold;
  float: right;
  margin-left: 5px;
}

.active:after {
  content: "\2212";
}

.panel {
  padding: 0 18px;
  background-color: white;
  max-height: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  transition: max-height 0.2s ease-out;
}
```

```html
<button class="accordion">Section 1</button>
<div class="panel">
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
</div>

<button class="accordion">Section 2</button>
<div class="panel">
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
</div>

<button class="accordion">Section 3</button>
<div class="panel">
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to bind the attributes that bootstrap relies on to toggle the div's accordingly:

- panel-heading: id, href, aria-controls
- panel-collapse: id, aria-labeledby

Try this example:

```
<div class="panel-heading" role="tab" [id]="'heading'+data.id">
    <h4 class="panel-title">
        <a role="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" [href]="'#collapse'+data.id" aria-expanded="true" [attr.aria-controls]="'collapse'+data.id">
            {{data.header}}
        </a>
    </h4>
</div>
<div [id]="'collapse'+data.id" class="panel-collapse collapse" role="tabpanel" [attr.aria-labelledby]="'heading'+data.id">
    <div class="panel-body">
        {{data.content}}
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you to use Data-parent property (a few examples), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15696365/twitter-bootstrap-collapse-plugin-how-to-enable-multiple-groups-to-be-opened)

If you want to do it manually, Bootstrap collapsing references are here, [collapse Referances](https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_ref_js_collapse.asp)

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(".btn-primary").click(function(){
    $(".collapse").collapse('toggle');
  });
  $(".btn-success").click(function(){
    $(".collapse").collapse('show');
  });
  $(".btn-warning").click(function(){
    $(".collapse").collapse('hide');
  });
});
</script>
```

Or you can control over multiplex panels,

```
$("#collapseOne, #collapseTwo").collapse('hide'); //Close multiple
```