# Collapsible of CSS and JS not working in Angular app

Tags: javascript, html, css, angular

I have implemented collapsible in plain html page as follow:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title></title>

<style>
button.accordion {
    background-color: #777;
    color: white;
    cursor: pointer;
    padding: 18px;
    width: 100%;
    border: none;
    text-align: left;
    outline: none;
    font-size: 15px;
}

button.accordion.active, button.accordion:hover {
    background-color: #555;
}

button.accordion:after {
    content: '\002B';
    color: white;
    font-weight: bold;
    float: right;
    margin-left: 5px;
}

button.accordion.active:after {
    content: '';
    background-image: url('download.jpg');
    display: inline-block;
    background-size: 30px 30px;
    width:30px;
    height:30px;
    transform:rotate(180deg);
}

div.panel {
    padding: 0 18px;
    background-color: #f1f1f1;
    max-height: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    transition: max-height 0.2s ease-out;
}


* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}


#myUL {
  list-style-type: none;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}
a{
     text-decoration: none;
     color:white;
}
</style>

</head>
<body>
<h2>Collapsible</h2>
<p>Click the button to toggle between showing and hiding the collapsible content.</p>




<div id="div2">
<button class="accordion"><a href="#">Addq</a></button>
<div class="panel"> 
  <p>Some collapsible content. Click the button to toggle between showing and hiding the collapsible content. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,ome Some collapsible content. Click the button to toggle between showing and hiding the collapsible content. </p>
<button class="accordion"><a href="#">Aollapsible</a></button>
<div class="panel">
  <p>sdfsdfsdfsdt amet,ome Some collapsible content. Click the button to toggle between showing and hiding the collapsible content. </p>
</div>
<button class="accordion"><a href="#" style="">Dollapsible</a></button>
<div class="panel">
  <p>qqqqqqqqqqqpsible content. consequat.</p>
</div>
<button class="accordion"><a href="#">Qollapsible</a></button>
<div class="panel">
  <p>zzzzzzzzzllapsible content. commodo consequat.</p>
</div>

</div>

<script>
var acc = document.getElementsByClassName("accordion");
var i;

for (i = 0; i < acc.length; i++) {
  acc[i].onclick = function() {
    this.classList.toggle("active");
    var panel = this.nextElementSibling;
    if (panel.style.maxHeight){
      panel.style.maxHeight = null;
    } else {
      panel.style.maxHeight = panel.scrollHeight + "px";
    } 
  }
}


</script>


</body>
</html>
```

JS Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/c2r70eh6/4/

But when I write same code in angular application, the collapsible doesnt expand.
While writing in Angular-
I put html code in html file of that component,
CSS in css file of that component and
JS I copied in index.html file.

Its working fine in simple html file. But not in angular. I checked all the ids they are correct.

Need your help. Thanks in advance!

Comment: which angular you are using? If you are using angular 2 and higher then it will not work.You need to write the logic in .ts

Comment: I m using Angular 5. Why it will not work @HaSnen Tai ?

Comment: okay so this won't work you need to achieve this with angular animations

Comment: Can u pls elaborate how to do this in angular animations @HaSnen Tai.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not really in support of what you're doing right now. But just for the sake of making it work, here's what you'll need to do in the Component Class:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
  acc = document.getElementsByClassName("accordion");

  ngOnInit() {
    for (let i = 0; i < this.acc.length; i++) {
      (<HTMLButtonElement>this.acc[i]).onclick = function () {
        this.classList.toggle("active");
        var panel = <HTMLDivElement>this.nextElementSibling;
        if (panel.style.maxHeight) {
          panel.style.maxHeight = null;
        } else {
          panel.style.maxHeight = panel.scrollHeight + "px";
        }
      }
    }
  }

}
```

---

> Here's a [**Working Sample StackBlitz**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/js-accordion-in-angular?file=src/app/app.component.ts) for your ref.

Comment: Its working now. But there is error on onclick. What might be the reason?

Comment: I want to know why should I not do like this?

Comment: To answer your first question, it's TypeScript. So it will not be able to properly determine whether a property is present on an inferred type. To make it do that, you'll have to type cast the `nextElementSibling` as an `HTMLDivElement`. Same for `panel`. I've updated my answer for the same. To answer your second question, I would want to understand what exactly are you trying to achieve by doing this in the first place.

Comment: Actually, its kind of help section where questions are header and on clicking on it-it should expand and show answer. And questions are going to come dynamically

Comment: Is the level of things consistent throughout? I mean is it going to be a two-level thing? Or does that change?

Comment: I didn't got what u r saying. All these questions will come from a json file with their associated answers

Comment: Share the sample json file and I'll update my implementation and show you the Angular way of doing it.

Comment: it was giving me error on ClassList . So I worked it out using Angular as per this ans -https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53369784/collapsible-accordion-in-angular

Answer (score 0):

You completely do not need the angular at all to collapse the panels - you can do it with straight css.

all you have to do is toggle the active class on the button click and then use the direct sibling combinator to target the next div and style it to be open or shut

```
.panel {
    padding: 0 18px;
    background-color: #f1f1f1;
    max-height: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    transition: max-height 0.2s ease-out;
}


.accordion.active + .panel {
    max-height: 500px;
    transition: max-height 0.2s ease-out;
}
```

```js
var acc = document.getElementsByClassName("accordion");
var i;

for (i = 0; i < acc.length; i++) {
  acc[i].onclick = function() {
    this.classList.toggle("active");
  }
}
```

```css
button.accordion {
    background-color: #777;
    color: white;
    cursor: pointer;
    padding: 18px;
    width: 100%;
    border: none;
    text-align: left;
    outline: none;
    font-size: 15px;
}

button.accordion.active, button.accordion:hover {
    background-color: #555;
}

button.accordion:after {
    content: '\002B';
    color: white;
    font-weight: bold;
    float: right;
    margin-left: 5px;
}

button.accordion.active:after {
    content: '';
    background-image: url('download.jpg');
    display: inline-block;
    background-size: 30px 30px;
    width:30px;
    height:30px;
    transform:rotate(180deg);
}

.panel {
    padding: 0 18px;
    background-color: #f1f1f1;
    max-height: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    transition: max-height 0.2s ease-out;
}



.accordion.active + .panel {
    max-height: 500px;
    transition: max-height 0.2s ease-out;
}


* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}


#myUL {
  list-style-type: none;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}
a{
     text-decoration: none;
     color:white;
}
```

```html
<h2>Collapsible</h2>
<p>Click the button to toggle the collapsible content.</p>



<div id="div2">
<button class="accordion"><a href="#">Addq</a></button>
<div class="panel"> 
  <p>Some collapsible content. Click the button to toggle between showing and hiding the collapsible content. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,ome Some collapsible content. Click the button to toggle between showing and hiding the collapsible content. 
<button class="accordion"><a href="#">Aollapsible</a></button>
<div class="panel">
  <p>sdfsdfsdfsdt amet,ome Some collapsible content. Click the button to toggle between showing and hiding the collapsible content. </p>
</div>
<button class="accordion"><a href="#" style="">Dollapsible</a></button>
<div class="panel">
  <p>qqqqqqqqqqqpsible content. consequat.</p>
</div>
<button class="accordion"><a href="#">Qollapsible</a></button>
<div class="panel">
  <p>zzzzzzzzzllapsible content. commodo consequat.</p>
</div>

</div>
```

Comment: @gavrif my question is about angular. My code works fine likewise u, but it wasnt running in angular